# How to add Edit button dynamically

Tags: javascript

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('request calling');
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "/dashboardUsers", false);
  xhttp.send();
  var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
  console.log(response);
  var table = document.getElementById("targettable");

  var btnEdit = document.createElement('button');
  btnEdit.innerHTML = "Edit";


  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    console.log("dashboard")
    console.log(response[i]);
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");

    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    var td3 = document.createElement("td");
    var td4 = document.createElement("td");
    var td5 = document.createElement("td");

    var txt1 = document.createTextNode(response[i].name);
    console.log(txt1);
    var txt2 = document.createTextNode(response[i].email);
    console.log(txt2);
    var txt3 = document.createTextNode(response[i].password);
    console.log(txt3);
    var txt4 = document.createTextNode(response[i].contact);
    console.log(txt4);

    td1.appendChild(txt1);
    td2.appendChild(txt2);
    td3.appendChild(txt3);
    td4.appendChild(txt4);

    tr.appendChild(td);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    tr.appendChild(td3);
    tr.appendChild(td4);

    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
};
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1 style="margin-top: 250px;">Users List </h1>
  <div>
    <br><br>
    <form action="/signup" method="get" class="box login">
      <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" value="Add User" tabindex="4">
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <table id="targettable">
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>
  </div>
</center>
```

I want to add edit button dynamically to this JavaScript code. I am trying to understanding the concept of dynamic buttons in JavaScript. Of course I went through Google, but unable to understand the concept.

This is the one of the file of my small project. When I execute my project, I will get sign up page and after enter user data, that will shows in dashboard, in a table format. Whenever I will add user data, I want to add edit button in each entry. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: While I understand you are fairly new to all of this, it may be best to work through a book or course on how to use JavaScript with HTML first.  This site is more geared towards specific questions not structural behaviors which is what you really need to understand.

Comment: This book is pretty good - https://eloquentjavascript.net/ - You also might like this series of videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkZNo7MFNFg&list=PLWKjhJtqVAbleDe3_ZA8h3AO2rXar-q2V

You'll need to understand HTML, the JavaScript DOM and JavaScript, as well as some server-side language, HTTP and other functionality.

Comment: This hyperlinked reference is conveniently organized https://javascript.info/, and I find this site extremely useful for picking up new concepts in web development https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps